# How to detect which transportReceiver is used in Axis2?

Tags: apache-axis, tomcat7

I am using tomcat7 and axis2 to deploy java web services.

In server.xml I configured three connectors (http, https wich server and client side certificates, https with server side certificate only):

```
<Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" clientAuth="true"  keystoreFile=... truststoreFile=... />
<Connector port="8444" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile=...  />
```

In axis2.xml I configured three transportReceivers:

```
<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8181</parameter>
    <parameter name="c1">none</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
    <parameter name="c2">serverAndClient</parameter>
</transportReceiver>

<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">
    <parameter name="port">8444</parameter>
    <parameter name="c3">serverOnly</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

That works fine ! All my web services are accessible on all ports as expected.

Unfortunately I would like to allow "login without password service" on 8443 only (because client will have certificate), and "login with password" on 8444.

In Java I tried:

```
MessageContext msg = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
TransportInDescription tin = msg.getTransportIn();
String str = tin.getParameters().toString();
```

but I always get:

```
[Parameter : port=8444, Parameter : c3=serverOnly]
```

It seems that one transport receiver always handles my messages. Is there a way to detect which transport receiver (or port) is really used for current invocation ?

BR,
Jacek

Comment: I know that I can define transport in services.xml: <transport>https</transport> but in my case I have two different https transports configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

I was wrong that only one transport receiver handles all messages. There are two (one for http and one for https). Unfortunately you can not define second https transport because axis2 holds all transport descriptors in hash map and name is a key so there will be always only one entry for "https" and you will get 8181 or 8444.

To solve this you can create your own servlet and store port number in MessageContext when message arrives. That is very easy:

```
public class MyServlet extends AxisServlet
{   
    protected MessageContext createMessageContext( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, boolean invocationType ) throws IOException
    {
        MessageContext mc = super.createMessageContext( request, response, invocationType );
        URL url = new URL( request.getRequestURL().toString() );
        mc.setProperty( "myPort", url.getPort() );
        return mc;      
    }
}
```

Of course you must put your class name in axis2/.../web.xml and restart tomcat.
Then you can check port number inside any axis2 invocation:

```
MessageContext mc = MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();
int port = ( Integer ) mc.getProperty( "myPort" );
```

Now I really get 8181, 8443 or 8444 :).

BR, Jacek